# Angular - Select - Directive on change value

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I want to create a directive (alert-select) that can make some actions when I change the value of a select element

```
<select alert-select [(ngModel)]="area_id">
    <option value="1">Area 1</option>
    <option value="2">Area 2</option>
</select>
```

I want (without use (change)) to alert(area_id) the value of the select every time I change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an event listener inside your directive

```
@HostListener('ngModelChange', ['$event'])
onChange(event) {
  console.log(event);
}
```

or

```
@HostListener('change', ['$event'])
onChange(event) {
  console.log(event.target.value);
}
```

(or both to make it work with or without `ngModel`)